# Subtract value from data with keys through multiple columns in R

Tags: r, data.table, primary-key

I have two `data.table`s with multiple columns as keys (they consists of the columns `record`, `dstPort`, `srcPort`, `proto`, `dstIP`, and `srcIP`).
Both have the same format.

dataset_1:

> ```
>     record dstPort srcPort proto         dstIP          srcIP  state        timestamp
> 1:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89     syn 1466580661185059
> 2:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89 syn_ack 1466520661604781
> 3:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89   close 1466532661885439
> 4:  state      80   55555   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89     syn 1466532661885440
> ```

and dataset_2:

> ```
>    record dstPort srcPort proto         dstIP          srcIP            state        timestamp
> 1:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89      established 1466537661727619
> 2:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89            close 1466532661986891
> 3:  state      80   44444   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89      established 1466537661727619
> ```

The following is what I would like to do for every key in the dataset:
I want to find the records (rows) with the same key and where a given state is available (i.e. state `syn` in dataset_1 and `established` in dataset_2 ).
For these records I want to subtract the timestamps from each other.
I.e.:

For every Key in dataset_1, i.e.:

`state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89` for state `syn` gives timestamp `1466580661185059`

and Key in dataset_2:

`state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89` for state `established` gives timestamp `1466537661727619`

After subtracting timestamps: 
1466580661185059-1466537661727619 = 42999457440

It could be that there is no record for a key in dataset_2. This is why sorting does not work (which is what all my tries were based to).
An exemplary try is (after having them sort which is not possible anymore):

```
dt_state1 <- subset(dt, state == 'established')
dt_state2 <- subset(dt, state == 'syn')
dt_delta_test <- data.table(x=(dt_state1$timestamp/1000)- (dt_state2$timestamp/1000),'timestamp'= dt_state1$timestamp-min(dt_state1$timestamp))
```

**Update 1:**
@lmo:

```
F1_in = as.data.table(read.csv(file=Filename, header=TRUE, sep=","))
keys=c("record","dstPort","srcPort","dstIP","srcIP")
state1 = 'syn'
state2 = 'established'
dt_state1 <- subset(F1_in, state == state2)
setkey(dt_state1, keys)
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : some columns are not in the data.table: keys
dt_state2 <- subset(F1_in, state == state1)
setkey(dt_state2, keys)
Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : some columns are not in the data.table: keys
dt_state1[dt_state2, timestamp - i.timestamp]
Error in `[.data.table`(dt_state1, dt_state2, timestamp - i.timestamp) : 
  When i is a data.table (or character vector), x must be keyed (i.e. sorted, and, marked as sorted) so data.table knows which columns to join to and take advantage of x being sorted. Call setkey(x,...) first, see ?setkey.
```

I don't know why this error occurs..

@toni057 Your solution does not change anything for me (I had to do some changes because it threw some errors). I tried the following code:

```
F1_in = as.data.table(read.csv(file=Filename, header=TRUE, sep=","))
keys=c("record","dstPort","srcPort","dstIP","srcIP")
state1 = 'syn'
state2 = 'established'
dt_state1 <- subset(F1_in, state == state2)
setkey(dt_state1, keys)
dt_state2 <- subset(F1_in, state == state1)
setkey(dt_state2, keys)

dt_state1 %>%
  filter("state" == 'syn') %>%
  left_join(filter(dt_state2, "state" == 'established'), by = keys) %>%
  mutate(timestamp_diff = timestamp.x - timestamp.y)
```

I also changed the dt of the second filter. But there is no change in dt_state1 at all..

Comment: see my updated answer. I've added the steps I used prior to the left join. Two issues with your code: 1. Don't use `subset`, instead use `[`. This is especially true with data.tables as the advantage of `subset` is greatly reduced. Instead of `dt_state1 <- subset(F1_in, state == state2)`, do `dt_state1 <- F1_in[state == 'syn', ]` 2. Use `setDT` rather than `as.data.table`. It creates a data.table by reference which is much more efficient. 3. use `setkeyv` rather than `setkey` when keying with a vector of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to take differences of the timestamps between the two data.tables where they both share the same key, you could use left join, and then calculate the difference:

```
# get stuff set up
library(data.table)
# convert data.frames to data.tables by reference
setDT(dt_state1)
setDT(dt_state2)
# set keys
setkey(dt_state1, record, dstPort, srcPort, proto, dstIP, srcIP)
setkey(dt_state2, record, dstPort, srcPort, proto, dstIP, srcIP)


# perform left join and get timestamp difference
dt_state1[dt_state2, timestamp - i.timestamp]

[1]  42999457440 -17000122838  -4999842180  47999198168 -12000382110      -101452     NA
```

This performs a left join (which subsets the observations in dt_state1 to include only those present in dt_state2) and subtracts dt_state2's timestamp from dt_state1.

The first entry of the returned vector is the value you listed in your example.

**data**

```
dt_state1 <- read.table(header=T, text="
record dstPort srcPort proto    dstIP   srcIP  state        timestamp
1:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89  syn 1466580661185059
2:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89 syn_ack 1466520661604781
3:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89 close 1466532661885439
4:  state      80   55555   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89   syn 1466532661885440")

dt_state2 <- read.table(header=T, text="
record dstPort srcPort proto     dstIP    srcIP    state   timestamp
1:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89  established 1466537661727619
2:  state      80   32768   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89  close 1466532661986891
3:  state      80   44444   tcp 192.168.101.5 192.168.101.89 established 1466537661727619")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

dt_state1 %>%
    filter(state == 'syn') %>%
    left_join(filter(dt_state2, state == 'established), by = insert all you keys here) %>%
    mutate(timestamp_diff = timestamp.x - timestamp.y)
```

Comment: It won't change dt_state1, but you can set dt_state1 <- ... before the code. Also I corrected the dt_state2 in join, thanks for noticing.